# Python datetime

Tags: python

Необходима дата в формате `RFC 3339 (1970-01-01T00: 00: 00Z)`

Я сделал так

```
d = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"
```

Как сделать, чтобы время стало на 6 часов меньше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()\
    .replace(microsecond=0)\
    .isoformat("T") + "Z"
```

Нужно использовать `utcnow()` чтоб получить время часового пояса `Z`.

Чтоб получить время на 6 часов меньше - вычитайте 6 часов.

Относительно UTC ( время 6 часов назад )

```
d = (
     datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
     ).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()+"Z"
```

Относительно локального времени

```
d = (
     datetime.datetime.now()
      - datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
     ).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()+"MSK"
```

Comment: показывает 2020-05-09T19:54:18Z, хотя у меня время 22:54

Comment: нет, не с урала

Comment: 22:54 - москва, 19:54 - 'Z','UTC'

Comment: ну так вы показываете текущее время, а мне нужно время на 6 часов меньше

Comment: если пишите букву Z, то надо ставить время по utc

Comment: Ладно, может я немного не понимаю, сейчас у меня 22:54.

Как мне показать время (6 часов назад), т.е 16:54 в формате UTC?

Comment: добавил в ответ